# Cloudformation IF issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In my CloudFormation I wanted to use `qa` mappings for other environment `qa-1`. Came up with following attempt, but CF was still complaining that the the `Mappings` section doesn't have `qa-1` section. The error message is: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template error: Mapping named 'qa-1' is not present in the 'Mappings' section of template.`

The shape of the mappings file is as follows:

```
Mappings:
  dev:
    us-east-1:
        ....
    eu-west-1
    ....
  qa:
    ....
```

no `qa-1` section as hyphens are not allowed in keys in Mappings session. This is the problem is what we're trying to work around with the `If`

Any hints what might be wrong? Are both clauses of the `If` evaluated no matter the value of the predicate?

```
Conditions:
  IsQA1: !Equals [!Ref Env, "qa-1"]
```

```
            Fn::If:
              - IsQA1
              - !FindInMap [ "qa", !Ref "AWS::Region", "Certificate" ]
              - !FindInMap [ !Ref Env, !Ref "AWS::Region", "Certificate" ]
```

Comment: Can you please show us the _exact_ error message? Also, if it is mentioning a Mappings section, please include that in your Question so that we can try to reproduce your situation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein updated with more details

Comment: Can you please provide enough of the template so that we can try running it ourselves? You have provided various bits and I don't know how they all link together. Can you make a minimum viable example that shows the problem?

Comment: The question is whether both !FindInMap will be evaluated no matter the value of IsQA1. I think the answer is yes, but wanted someone to confirm...